# ReactNative: this.setState Error: null is not an object

Tags: reactjs, react-native

React script

```
class TransactionsList extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            activeAccountId: "",
            accessToken: "",
            TransactionsData: "",
        };
    }
    replaceRoute(route, passProps) {
        this.props.replaceRoute(route, passProps);
    }
    async _getToken() {
        try {
            let accessToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('AUTH_TOKEN');
            if(!accessToken) {
                this.replaceRoute('login');
            } else {
                this.setState({accessToken: accessToken})
            }
        } catch(error) {
            Alert.alert('Print Errorr', error.message)
            this.replaceRoute('login');
        }
    }
    componentWillMount(){
        this._getToken()
        let token = 'Token '+this.state.accessToken
        this.load_data(token)
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <Container>
            // other code
            </Container>
        )
    }
}
```

Got error in setState in getToken below is catch(error) block output

> Print Error null is not an object(evaluating
>   prevComponentInstance._currentElement)

But same above code works in other screens.

Comment: Maybe you need to bind `this` explicitly while invoking `getToken` method to be `this._getToken().bind(this)`

Comment: @BasimHennawi tried adding `this._getToken = this._getToken().bind(this)`  in constructor method. got error setState can only be called on mounted component.

Comment: Exactly, you can only change the state (by `setState` method) on a mounted component so either in the constructor or on `componentWillRecieveProps` in case you pass your props.

Comment: I need to access `Token` and some other variable in componentWillmount method to fetch data from APIs.? I tried using setState. Any other solution.

Comment: Better dispatch actions in `componentWillMount` that what `redux` framework is up for, it helps your data changes to be uni-directional flow. Then there are `reducers` listens to that changes and update your state. I recommend you read about `Flux` or `Redux` framework.

Answer (score 1):

It is not advisable to make api calls in `componentWillMount` because it is possible that the component will not have been mounted when the api call has finished and you call `setState`.

Instead, you should make api calls in `componentDidMount`. According to the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount):

> componentDidMount() is invoked immediately after a component is
>   mounted. Initialization that requires DOM nodes should go here. If you
>   need to load data from a remote endpoint, this is a good place to
>   instantiate the network request. Setting state in this method will
>   trigger a re-rendering.

And, you also need to bind _getToken as @Jazib mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind `_getToken` method using something like this:

```
this._getToken().bind(this)
```

Or you can do this in the constructor for better code (I prefer this one):

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        activeAccountId: "",
        accessToken: "",
        TransactionsData: "",
    };
    this._getToken() = this._getToken().bind(this)
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: added `this._getToken = this._getToken().bind(this)` in constructor method. got Warning: setState(...): can only updated a mounted component ot mounting component.

Comment: I think this may have something to do with async call that you're making to fetch token. 

Although setting state in componentWillMount is allowed and it shouldn't  give warning, I think in this case, your code may have already entered rendering phase when the result of token gets back.
Try moving this._getToken() call to componentDidMount().

Answer (score 0):

I know I am replying a bit late but a better way is to use an arrow function instead of using bind on a named function. So you could write your `_getToken` method like this:

`const _getToken = async () => {
  // your logic here
}`

The arrow function here implicitly assigns the current instance of the component to `this` keyword whereas in the named function you have to give the `this` keyword the context by using `bind` method as mentioned by others.

Also, `componentWillMount` is now deprecated and its better if you call your method in `componentDidMount`